# CSS menu drops up instead of down

Tags: css

I have a CSS drop down menu that drops up instead of down. What could be wrong? here is the code and the aspx tags related to the problem. this is inside the master page; also on the pages inside ContentPlaceHolder1 eveything inside  tags!

```
.wrapper {
 position:relative; height:25px;
}

.mainmenu {

 z-index:100;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:90%;
 line-height:25px;
 left:50%; 
 margin-left:-303px; 
 width:606px;
} 

ul.menu {

 padding:0; 
 margin:0; 
 list-style:none; 
 width:100px; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 float:left; 
 margin-right:1px;
} 

ul.menu a {
 text-decoration:none; 
 color:#fff; 
 padding-left:5px;
 position:absolute;
}

ul.menu li.list {    
float:left;
width:250px;
margin:-32767px -125px 0px 0px;
background:url(images/top1.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}    
ul.menu li.list a.category {
position:absolute;
z-index:50;
display:block;
float:left;
width:120px;
margin-top:32767px;
background:transparent;
}    
ul.menu li.list a.category:hover,
ul.menu li.list a.category:focus,
ul.menu li.list a.category:active {
 margin-right:1px;
 background-image:url(images/tophover1.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:left top;

}

ul.submenu {
 float:left; 
 padding:25px 0px 0px 0px; 
 margin:0; 
 list-style:none; 
 background-image:url(images/tophover1.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:left top;
 margin:-25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

ul.submenu li a {    
float:left;
width:120px;    
background:#369;
clear:left;
}    
ul.submenu li a.endlist {
 background:url(images/bottom1.png);
}     
ul.submenu li a.endlist:hover,
ul.submenu li a.endlist:focus,
ul.submenu li a.endlist:active {
background:url(images/bottomhover1.png);
}

ul.submenu a:hover,
ul.submenu a:focus,
ul.submenu a:active {
background:#900;
margin-right:1px;
}
// and here is the portion of aspx
<div id="slidemenu" >
     <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="History.aspx">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="....aspx">....</a></li>

        <li><a href="Careers.aspx">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="..."><span> ... </span> </a></li>    
     <li class="list">
 <a class="category" href="....aspx"> ... </a>
 <ul class="submenu" >
  <li><a href="http://www.....com/">1st drop down menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www....com/">2nd drop down menu</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<!--    ------------ --> 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: post the code for the css please

Comment: I agree with Gustavo, we need to check the CSS, it might even help having the CSS and HTML. If the site is live, the link would also help out.

Comment: I think it's because the server is in the southern hemisphere.  Kind of like how their toilets run backwards.

Comment: @ChrisLively ^ for coming up with something better than I was going to.

Comment: I have tried the solutions proposed, but here is what works, I still though have the droped down list going into under the <div> below it. How do I solve it. here is my css:

Comment: #nav li ul {
 /*-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);   
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 -transform: rotate(180deg); */
 
  position:absolute;
 left: 0; 
 bottom: -60px; 
 /*margin-left: -999em; */
}

Comment: What worked is the: bottom: -60px; but I still have the problem of the menu going under the dive below it. Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Apply this css to your menu text blocks:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);  
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Comment: Best. Answer. Ever. I wish I could give you more than a +1.

Comment: @NathanArthur:  Thank you.  Your support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should post some code, but I wrote something that may help:

see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/HE8uj/

pasted code:

> ```
> <div class="menu">
>     <em>hover me!</em>
>     <ul>
>         <li> item one </li>
>         <li> item two </li>
>         <li> item three </li>
>     </ul>
> </div>
> ```

```
.menu {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin:1px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.menu * {
    display:block;
    padding:0; margin:0;
}
.menu em {
    padding:5px;
}
.menu ul {
    display:none;
}
.menu:hover ul {
    display:block;  
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:100%; /* change to TOP and it will drop down */
    border:solid 1px black;
    background: #fff;
}
.menu li {
    padding:5px;   
}
```

Comment: What worked is the: bottom: -60px; but I still have the problem of the menu going under the div tag below it. Any ideas

Comment: If you analise my example in jsfiddle you will see that you dont need to set a magic number value, and it will expand if necessary. Also, there is NO WAY to know why your random div is behaving this way if you dont post any contextual code.